# Is the category of short exact sequences of abelian groups abelian?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

I've been trying to figure out if the category of short exact sequences of abelian groups is abelian. It's clearly additive, and it has all of its kernels, but Im not sure about cokernels. I can't produce a solid counterexample, and don't know if it exists. Is the category abelian? And if not, what witnesses it's failure? I was thinking of the cokernel of a sequence like 0->Z->Z but I'm not sure (sorry for the poor formatting, I'm on my phone)

Comment: By duality, cokernels should work exactly like kernels.

Comment: Hmm, then is the category abelian?

Comment: Well, I don't mean to be picky, but this question was supposed to be part of the "building up to"  the snakes lemma, and thus I would ideally like to do it without directly invoking the snakes lemma

Comment: The addendum at the end of the answer does not use the snake lemma, and the paragraph before that explains why the category is not balanced.

Comment: You're right, spoke too soon. I'll mark the question as a duplicate then.